# Memory leak in a small operation

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

There is a possible memory leak in this statement for a very large string (`tempText` can grow as big as ~10mb).

```
string strXML = new string(tempText.Where(ch => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch)).ToArray());
```

Memory allocated for `strXML` doesn't get released even after exiting the function. And I've to call this function multiple times. Any possible solution, without having this string as a class variable? 
I'm not very familiar with C# memory management, can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with the way you create `strXML`. How do you use `strXML` after initialization? Do you add it to collections? Do you use it in lambdas where `strXML` could be captured?

Comment: Have you used a memory profiler to ensure that it's actually the memory allocated for `strXML` that's being retained? Is another reference to the string being retained anywhere?).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight later i use it with StringReader, which is inside using()
Vlad-- our users launch our product in morning and keep it running till end of the day. It is creating problem, after 4-5 hours.

Comment: Allocate 5MB. Allocate 2MB. Release 5MB. How much memory is used? 7MB. The program cannot truly release the first 5MB because there is something allocated after it. It may reuse those 5MB later if you try to allocate something else that fits there.

Comment: I didnt use memory profiler, ANTS crashing mercilessly. 
I'm parallelly watching task manager to confirm that this line takes large memory but not freeing even after exiting function call.

Comment: @Vlad Outside of the use of the `Intern` method, only compile time literal strings are interned.

Comment: @rplusg: Why and how have you arrived at the conclusion that this line of code possibly causes a memory leak?

Comment: @stakx as i already mentioned, I'm parallelly watching task manager to confirm that this line takes large memory but not freeing even after exiting function call.

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector doesn't collect objects the instance that their lifetime ends.  It executes periodically, based on it's perceived need, to free up memory.  The string will be *eventually* collected at some indeterminate point in time after it is long longer referenced by any rooted object.

Comment: I really wish, there is a way, i can force GC to clearup objects i donot need.

Comment: @rplusg Why would you need to do that?  It's almost certainly going to be smarter than you are at determining when the appropriate time to perform a collection is.

Comment: I understand about GC being smarter, but in this particular case, in this function, i'm converting very large string into DataView and binding to UI. But if user launches UI 100 times and closes 100 times. This memory is not getting released at all...even after waiting for an hour.

Comment: @rplusg Then odds are pretty high that the objects is still accessible in your application; it's lifetime hasn't ended, it is still accessible through a rooted object, and manually starting the GC wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When you build up a large object, it will remain in memory for much longer than other small objects.

Read up on the large object heap and generation 2 garbage collection... it gets technical but those two terms should suffice to point out what's going on here.

That's why you are not seeing the garbage collector reclaim that memory as quickly as you'd like.

In order to overcome this, either allocate work buffers once and reuse them, or work on the data in smaller chunks.